# Doubts about what is growing in my bacteriological cultivation

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, mycology

Foreword: I don't belong to the field at all, I am a high school student with a passion for science so I apologise in advance if I formulate the question incorrectly or make some mistakes.

Out of personal curiosity, I tried growing a colony of bacteria.

I was amazed today when I opened the culture and found a kind of white spider's web with a few black dots hanging from it. Can anyone tell me what this is? I assume it is mould, but I am not sure.
[image: my colony]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please tell us what sort of media you are using — that may be of some help in narrowing down an identification. However, note that fungi are notoriously difficult to identify based on appearance. That being said, the white threads with black spots does resemble common [bread mold (Rhizopus stolonifer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhizopus_stolonifer).

Comment: If black dots seem to be swimming then it might be a yeast infection.

Comment: Almost certainly a mold (the black dots being some sort of fruiting structure with spores). As far as which mold, it's difficult to say. The typical way to ID a mold is to look at spore morphology under phase-contrast microscopy, but even then it can be difficult (sometimes impossible) to distinguish between common genera by microscopy alone.